# How to define the manufacturer of laptop touchpad?

Tags: touchpad

I'am trying to instal driver of touchpad of my laptop Toshiba Satellite T130. (Part No.: PST3AE-03601VRU) Toshiba webpage

http://www.toshiba.eu/innovation/download_drivers_bios.jsp?service=EU&selCategory=2&selFamily=2&selSeries=248&selProduct=862&selShortMod=921&language=13&selOS=30&selType=all&yearupload=&monthupload=&dayupload=&useDate=null&mode=allMachines&search=&action=search&macId=&country=170&page=3

proposes two version of driver for my OS (Win7 64 Home Premium) of two different manufacturer: Synaptics and Alps Electric. How to define which one I should to instal?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In general, attempting to install a driver for which you have no hardware will fail with an informative error message, so the risk is minimal.

In specific, you can discover the manufacturer of a given device from its PCI vendor and device IDs, as discussed [here](http://www.technibble.com/pcidatabase-repair-tool-of-the-week/).

Comment: Thank you for answer. Unfortunately, I can't find touchpad in device manager. It works properly but I'd like to instal the newest drived for it. I'll try to instal one driver and if fail another one. Thanks again.